# Remote SSH git pull asks id_rsa passphrase every time

Tags: git, github, ssh

I'm trying to `git pull` from another computer i'm connected to through SSH. Every single time I execute `git pull` on this remote desktop, I get prompted

`Enter passphrase for key '/home/**me**/.ssh/id_rsa':`

However when I  `git pull` from the same location but directly on the computer, nothing is prompted and the rsa identification to github works.

***Tries :***

I have tried to create a second RSA key authentification (renamed `id_rsa_2`) from the ssh control but nothing changes, it still asks for the original passphrase (`id_rsa`, not `id_rsa_2`)

Comment: Here is my answer to the same problem: http://askubuntu.com/a/362287/148451

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are doing `git pull` from your DE, your key is stored in `gnome-keyring` or `ssh-agent`. This stores your passphrase and doesn't ask for it every time.

If you connect using ssh, you don't have the DE and and `ssh-agent`, so there is no place to store the passphrase, but you can do it by hand:

```
eval `ssh-agent` # start your agent to store your keys
ssh-add  # asks for passphrase
# or ssh-add /path/to/your/key
ssh remote # will not ask for password again
```

Comment: Hi,
I am using this to AWS EC2. But this only works for one session. It asks for passphrase again when I do git pull after a new SSH to the server.

Comment: @SandeepC yes, the `ssh-agent` lasts only for your single session. If you want to use it for more sessions, I would recommend you to copy the key to your local machine, add it to your local `ssh-agent` and then connect with `ssh-agent` forwarding.